# Capturar botões pressionados em controle de videogame de forma confiável

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Eu quero usar um controle de XBox pra controlar um programa. Não é um jogo, é só uma aplicação *Windows Forms*. Eu não quero usar XNA porque não quero forçar o download dos redistribuíveis quando for usar minha aplicação noutra máquina.

Estou fazendo algumas experiências mexendo com DirectX, usando algumas bibliotecas que o encapsulam. Pela documentação, me parece que não existe evento de aperto de botão.

Então estou a buscar uma alternativa. Eu tentei usar um temporizador (com a classe *System.Windows.Forms.Timer*), em cujo evento leio o estado do controle dessa forma:

```
private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    State s = controller.GetState();
    stateLabel.Text = s.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.A ? "A" : "";
}
```

Problema: entre duas execuções desse método, eu não tenho como saber se o usuário apertou o botão duas vezes, ou se ele esteve segurando o botão o tempo todo. Mesmo utilizando a informação do número do pacote enviado pelo controle não ajuda, pois um pacote é enviado ao menor contato com os direcionais analógicos ou com os triggers nos ombros do controle.

Alguém conhece alguma forma mais confiável de se fazer isso?

Comment: Você está enfrentando problemas na prática, ou é só uma possibilidade que te ocorreu? Tudo o que tenho lido sobre o assunto de um jeito ou de outro envolve *polling* tal como você está fazendo, então infelizmente não tenho nada melhor a sugerir... Mas talvez alguém com mais experiência tenha uma alternativa melhor.

Comment: É uma possibilidade por enquanto, mas será prático em breve. Estou tentando adaptar controles para que pessoas paraplégicas possam usar. Não para jogar, mas para operar um computador.

Comment: Talvez fosse o caso de você repensar seus requisitos de usabilidade então. Afinal, seu método atual só trará problemas se houver a possibilidade da pessoa apertar o botão várias vezes em sequência mais rápido do que seu timer consegue acompanhar. Se não houver **motivo** para ela fazer isso (i.e. se não houver nenhum caso de uso em que essa ação produza um resultado desejável) então a necessidade de se distinguir entre os dois casos se torna menos importante. Não que isso responda à pergunta - acho que ela ainda é válida - mas na prática pode ser útil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao invés de implementar isso em um timer, porque não usar uma outra thread, e verificar continuamente o estado do controle, disparando um evento no form quando um botão for pressionado e quando for solto.

**Código do Form:**

```
public partial class FormWithExternalEvents : Form
{
    private GamepadEvents gpe;

    public FormWithExternalEvents()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        gpe = new GamepadEvents();
        gpe.JoystickButtonDown += b =>
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired) this.Invoke((GamepadButtonEvent) gpe_JoystickButtonDown);
            else gpe_JoystickButtonDown(b);
        };
        gpe.JoystickButtonUp += b =>
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired) this.Invoke((GamepadButtonEvent)gpe_JoystickButtonUp);
            else gpe_JoystickButtonUp(b);
        };
        var thread = new Thread(gpe.Run);
        thread.Start();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    void gpe_JoystickButtonUp(SharpDX.XInput.GamepadButtonFlags button)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void gpe_JoystickButtonDown(SharpDX.XInput.GamepadButtonFlags button)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Código da classe que ficará rodando em outra thread:**

```
public delegate void GamepadButtonEvent(GamepadButtonFlags button);

public class GamepadEvents
{
    public event GamepadButtonEvent JoystickButtonUp;
    public event GamepadButtonEvent JoystickButtonDown;

    private bool[] buttonsBools = new bool[32];

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var controller = new Controller();
            State s = controller.GetState();

            ButtonSignal(0, GamepadButtonFlags.DPadUp, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.DPadUp) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(1, GamepadButtonFlags.DPadDown, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.DPadDown) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(2, GamepadButtonFlags.DPadLeft, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.DPadLeft) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(3, GamepadButtonFlags.DPadRight, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.DPadRight) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(4, GamepadButtonFlags.Start, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.Start) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(5, GamepadButtonFlags.Back, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.Back) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(6, GamepadButtonFlags.LeftThumb, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.LeftThumb) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(7, GamepadButtonFlags.RightThumb, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.RightThumb) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(8, GamepadButtonFlags.LeftShoulder, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.LeftShoulder) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(9, GamepadButtonFlags.RightShoulder, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.RightShoulder) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(10, GamepadButtonFlags.A, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.A) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(11, GamepadButtonFlags.B, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.B) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(12, GamepadButtonFlags.X, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.X) != 0);
            ButtonSignal(13, GamepadButtonFlags.Y, (s.Gamepad.Buttons & GamepadButtonFlags.Y) != 0);

            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    private void ButtonSignal(int btnIdx, GamepadButtonFlags gamepadButton, bool pressed)
    {
        bool wasPressed = buttonsBools[btnIdx];
        buttonsBools[btnIdx] = pressed;

        if (wasPressed && !pressed)
            this.JoystickButtonUp(gamepadButton);

        if (!wasPressed && pressed)
            this.JoystickButtonDown(gamepadButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso funciona perfeitamente. Com um intervalo suficientemente pequeno entre verificações do estado do controle (utilizo 10-15ms), posso tratar os casos de botão segurado e botão pressionado várias vezes repetidamente como a mesma coisa.